# The attribute [resource] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel API, I added [Model::preventAccessingMissingAttributes();](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_preventAccessingMissingAttributes) to the `boot` function of `AppServiceProvider.php`.
Since then, I get this error in my API response:

```
The attribute [resource] either does not exist or was not retrieved for model [App\\Models\\Vehicle].
```

**DefaultCollection.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class DefaultCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
     /**
     * The resource collection class to be used.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $resourceClass;

    /**
     * Set the resource collection class.
     *
     * @param  string  $resourceClass
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setResourceClass(string $resourceClass)
    {
        $this->resourceClass = $resourceClass;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Customize the pagination information for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  array $paginated
     * @param  array $default
     * @return array
     */
    public function paginationInformation($request, $paginated, $default)
    {
        $default['count'] = $default['meta']['total'];
        unset($default['meta']);

        return $default;
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @return array<int|string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        $resourceClass = $this->resourceClass;

        return [
            'data' => $resourceClass::collection($this->collection),
        ];
    }
}
```

**VehicleController.php**

```php
public function index()
    {
        $vehicles = Vehicle::with(['manufacturer', 'colors'])
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(50);
        $collection = new DefaultCollection($vehicles);
        $collection->setResourceClass(VehicleResource::class);
        return $collection;
    }
```

I use this DefaultCollection to make a custom paginationInformation.
I'd appreciate it if someone could let me know how to resolve this error.

**UPDATE: At first sight, it seems the root cause may be this line: [https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Resources/Json/PaginatedResourceResponse.php#L31[2].](https://github.com/illuminate/http/blob/master/Resources/Json/PaginatedResourceResponse.php#L31%5B2%5D.)**